# How can a proxy + VPN be faster than VPN alone?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, bittorrent

I use a VPN service (PIA) and was downloading some popular torrents such as Ubuntu. I have the regular VPN client setup to encrypt all traffic. PIA also offers a SOCKS 5 proxy. I set the torrent client to use the proxy and when I did speeds went way up, even before I disabled the VPN. How is it possible that this is faster? I get that the VPN takes some time, with the encrypting traffic, but how could the proxy be so much faster? I'm guessing it has to do with the way P2P works and all the connections were being combined into one? The device had very limited resources, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Does your BitTorrent client use the proxy for actual P2P connections, not just for accessing trackers? Do the proxy server and the VPN server have exactly the same IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The
[PIA documentation](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/helpdesk/kb/articles/do-you-offer-a-socks5-proxy)
says this about the SOCKS5 proxy:

> Although quite different from a VPN, we provide a SOCKS5 Proxy with all accounts in the event users require this feature.

My understanding is that the proxy perhaps routes your access through the PIA servers,
but this is not a VPN.
This means that your communications are not encrypted, therefore are faster,
but can be read by any man-in-the-middle (for example your ISP).

Answer (score 0):

SOCKS5 Proxy servers are able to use both UDP and also TCP, that could be one of the reasons why you see a difference with speed. It is also possible that the proxy was able to cut down a few hops for you, making the destination closer & the downloads faster! Hope this helps!

Based on another VPN service that serves socks5, 
https://nordvpn.com/blog/socks5-proxy/